Where does Actino- come from in the genus Actinomycetota?
This comment under Bacteria trapped in crystal inclusions found 'alive' after 50,000 years - what were they eating all that time? links to Quintana, Badillo ann Maldonado (2013) Characterisation of the first actinobacterial group isolated from a Mexican extremophile environment. The term "Actinobacteria" seems to be synonymous with the phylum Actinomycetota.
According to van Bergeijk et al. (2020) Ecology and genomics of Actinobacteria: new concepts for natural product discovery

Actinobacteria constitute a highly diverse bacterial phylum with an unrivalled metabolic versatility. They produce most of the clinically used antibiotics and a plethora of other natural products with medical or agricultural applications. Modern ‘omics’-based technologies have revealed that the genomic potential of Actinobacteria greatly outmatches the known chemical space.

I have found Phylum Actinomycetota:

Etymology: Ac.ti.no.my.ce.to’ta. N.L. masc. n. Actinomyces, type genus of the phylum; L. neut. pl. n. suff. -ota, ending to denote a phylum; N.L. neut. pl. n. Actinomycetota, the Actinomyces phylum

But so far I have not found the origin of the "Actino-" part of the genus name.
Question: Where does Actino- come from in the genus Actinomycetota?
Is it perhaps related to actinide somehow?

This one is easily answered.
The Actino part of is derived from the first described genus in this group; Actinomyces and means "ray" as the formation of a colony has a light-ray-like appearance, as seen in this photo from Wikimedia:

Image attribution: US gov, Public domain, via Wikimedia Commons
Incidentally the "myce" part means "fungus", as it was thought from the appearance of the colonies, which sometimes show mycelia-like formations, that they were fungi, until later proven to be bacteria.

Interesting! So in a way "actino-" is sort-of related to actinides, since they also have rays (of emitted ionizing radiation).

@uhoh Yes, the word is the same. It's Greek and was more commonly used about 100+ years ago in the literature - a lot of early science fiction uses the term actinic.
